# VBA button is not working

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I want to select an excel file from my computer and insert it into a database. I have some code working properly but when I click on the cancel button it does not cancel it and keeps doing same work as open button.

```
Sub GetDataFromClosedBook()
'On Error GoTo myError
Dim mydata As String
'data location & range to copy
mydata = "='C:\Users\IT.int08\Downloads\[close.xls]Sheet1'!$A1:$C1000" '<< change as required
'link to worksheet
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:C1000") '<< change as required

.Formula = mydata
'convert formula to text
.Value = .Value
Cells.Replace What:="'", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
        xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Counter As String
Counter = Cells.Item(2, 4)

Dim IRow As Integer
IRow = Cells.Item(2, 4)
IRow = IRow + 1
Dim rgno, taxpname As String

        conn.Provider = "sqloledb"
        'conn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways
        conn.Open "Data Source=10.10.1.139;Initial Catalog=time;user id=sa;password=11"

        Do Until .Cells(IRow, 1) = 0 Or Null
            rgno = .Cells(IRow, 2)
            taxpname = .Cells(IRow, 3)
            Cells.Item(2, 4) = IRow
         Dim Qu As String
         If Len(rgno) >= 13 Then

            Qu = "insert into dbo.rough (NTN_no,CNIC,TAXPAYERNAME) values ('" & "" & "', '" & rgno & "', '" & taxpname & "')"
            conn.Execute (Qu)
            ElseIf Len(rgno) < 13 Then
            Dim asdf As String
            asdf = "insert into dbo.rough (NTN_no,CNIC,TAXPAYERNAME) values ('" & rgno & "', '" & "" & "', '" & taxpname & "')"
 conn.Execute (asdf)
 End If
 IRow = IRow + 1

 DoEvents      
 Loop       
'myError:
'MsgBox ("record is missing")
 Sheet1.Cells.Clear

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: what line errors?

Comment: not show error it working but when prompt open and click on cancel button then it insert into database

Comment: can you show me a screenshot please of what you see

Comment: please execute code @mo.h

Comment: I don't see where in your code you are asking input from the user?

Comment: i am not asking for input but i assign path to variable in 5th line

Answer (score 0):

Where does the promt occures? 
Usually, you have to tell the machine what to do on "cancel", smth. like:

```
If [PROMPT] = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: line no 8 prompt occur

Comment: ".Formula = mydata" ??

Comment: iam new in vba just copy from google i dont know ".formula=mydata" what actualy  do

Comment: i just want to copy data  from close excel file and insert into database

Comment: I still did not get it. You do not have a prompt so confirm, but your cancel button is not working. Do you have assigned the cancel button with the correct makro?